# Click Function Issue In jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote this code in jQuery and when i click on the **.l_7** element , the code alert twice **Yes!**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.l_7').click(function() {
        alert("Yes!");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="p_like l_7" >
    <span class="nol" >1 </span>
</div>
```

What's the problem ? and how can i fix it ?

Comment: Show some html which reproduce your problem?

Comment: It's quite hard to help as is. Please add the markup. If it alerts twice, **chances are you have included this snippet twice in your source code** so _please double check the file where this code appears is not included twice._, this could also come from the fact that one `.l_7` element have another `.l_7` element as a child somewhere and you click on that child.

Comment: If the same script then there is not chance for twice alert

Comment: I know that's impossible but it alert twice , and i don't know why .

Comment: provide us your html, otherwise it's quite impossible to help you

Comment: Is this the only JS code ?

Comment: have you included the script twice by mistake? I've done it before :)

Comment: See edited question and run snippet your code works perfect .Problem is not in this code .

Comment: it already alert twice . when i find the element in the inspect element of the firefox , it was to javascript code : one in the main.js that has the above code , and the other one was jquery.js has the function again. what's happened?

Comment: If you can give us a full example of the code where the alert actually is triggered twice, we can take a look at it but it's not really possible to give a proper answer with the information you've given so far.

Comment: it solved. the script file was embeded two time !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click", '.l_7',function(){
    //Your code here
    });
});
```

and you maybe run the code two time , check it!